# Android VPN Issue

Tags: android, vpn

I am using Android VPN(Android.net package and VPN service class). when I made audio/video call from my App everything works fine(got data packets just after clicking the button). but when I click on search TAB(for sticker). After clicking for next few second, we did not receive any data packet form VPN TUN. But after few seconds everything starts working fine, and we able to find the stickers(means there is a few second latency in searching). Without VPN there is no latency in receiving the packets.

Answer (score -1):

You are right there is a slight difference between using a vpn and without, but also speed varies with different VPN, I use Ivacy VPN on my android devices and I am satisfied with the speed.
https://www.ivacy.com/blog/android-users-rejoice-ivacy-vpn-for-android-is-here/

Comment: Yes with other VPN it's working fine. But I want Use android TUN VPN. With TUN/TAP calling is working fine. but Search tap is not.(for search there is a 5-8 sec latency). With other VPN search tab working fine.